# How many records can be in S3 put() event lambda trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to have some lambda function which got this flow:

> Triggered S3 put file event -> lambda function -> insert row to DynamoDB

When I'm creating a test using AWS from the lambda screen, I got this example with only 1 record in the `Records` list:

```
{
  "Records": [    //  <<<----------------only 1 element 
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "object": {
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
          "name": "roeyg-oregon-s3-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried several ways to see if it's possible to get a list with more than one element in this list, like using CLI or uploading several files together or even a whole folder, in all of these scenarios I got one item per one event.

My question is to know if there can be a scenario in which I can get more than one file at one event?

By that, I would change my code to have a loop and not a reference to the first element like AWS suggested.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Given your current configuration, you will only get one record per invocation. This is because each distinct S3 Put Event triggers a distinct S3 event notification with your AWS Lambda function as the recipient. Lambda can then process up to [100 concurrent executions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) by default, a limit that can be automatically raised depending on your incoming event rate.

AWS Lambda receives `Records` as a collection because it is using S3 Event Notifications to send the event to lambda, and thus using the [S3 notification event message structure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html). In [anticipation of event types that may return more than one record](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=592264#592264), the format exists as a collection. You can see a full list of S3 event notification types [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations).

This doesn't impact S3 notifications from events like `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`, so you're fine to leave the function as-is because that is how Put notifications are intended to work -- `one event -> one notification -> one invokation`.

---

That said, if you still want your code to be able to handle multiple Records per invokation, there is no harm in writing it to either:

- process records in a loop (there is an example available in the docs for this: the [python example deployment code that AWS provides](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python) loops instead of grabbing only the first record). If you go this route, consider adding further logic to filter duplicates if your application can't tolerate them.
- log an error on >1 Records.

Comment: As I said, I code my function using JS and aws-sdk, so it's ok just add a loop?

Comment: Yes, the language has no bearing on whether it is or is not ok to just add a loop. It was just the preference of the documention writer for that python example to just loop, and the preference of the JS writer to not.

Comment: I there any config file that can set the possible files amout per each event ?

Comment: No, not really. Not beyond what blueskin has suggested.  You could set up a pre-processing piece to batch your put events and then process them all at once based on some timer or max size trigger, but that's beyond the scope of this question.  You should probably [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: So why worth adding the loop for ?

Comment: That's still stange that in [the AWS python sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python) they loop on records

Comment: But in [this other AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) this DON'T use a loop and use `Records[0]` instead

Comment: Link 404 in 2022: "anticipation of event types that may return more than one record"

Answer (score 2):

1. Upload files to a different new folder (possibly with timestamp) in S3.
2. Once the files are uploaded, put a file which contains the path to the above folder in the S3 folder/bucket (which triggers the Lambda).
3. The Lambda will now be triggered with the key to the file containing the path to the list of uploaded files

Comment: Good idea, i'll take it into consideration.

Comment: As an alternative, you could push the records to S3 via Kinesis firehose, which will chunk the records into individual large objects, thus producing just one notification and allowing you to parse multiple records with one lambda function call.