# Is it possible for S3 to send multiple records?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

We're trying to confirm if when there is a PUT event on our bucket that is subscribed to SNS, is it possible for S3 to send multiple records?  Here is the message format, notice Records is an array.

```
   "Records":[  
     {  
        "eventVersion":"2.1",
        "eventSource":"aws:s3",
        "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
        "eventTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",
        "userIdentity":{  
           "principalId":"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE"
        },
        "requestParameters":{  
           "sourceIPAddress":"127.0.0.1"
        },
        "responseElements":{  
           "x-amz-request-id":"C3D13FE58DE4C810",
           "x-amz-id-2":"FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD"
        },
        "s3":{  
           "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
           "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
           "bucket":{  
              "name":"mybucket",
              "ownerIdentity":{  
                 "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
              },
              "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
           },
           "object":{  
              "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
              "size":1024,
              "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
              "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko",
              "sequencer":"0055AED6DCD90281E5"
           }
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this answer from another question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40767563/3844353

[Short version](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=592264#592264) :

> Currently, all S3 event notifications have a single event per notification message. We might include multiple records as we add new event types in the future. This is also a message format that is shared across other AWS services, and other services can include multiple records.