# Configure multiple delete event in S3/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a Lambda function that gets triggered on S3 delete events.  If multiple items are deleted at once, I want to use an S3 batch job.  What I can't figure out or find in the documentation is what an event like that would look like.  I'd assume it would just have multiple similar items in Records and I could iterate through, get all the keys, and then batch delete, but I can't confirm that.  I've searched the documentation, and I built a test Lambda that would just log the event, but that came through as multiple distinct events.  I'm stumped as to how to do what I'm trying here.

Comment: Not clear what your question is. The objects have already been deleted, presumably, as that is what triggers your Lambda function. Why do you need to batch delete anything in the Lambda function? You'll receive an array of event records with 1+ records (one record per object). I'm not aware of a guarantee that you'll get at most 1 record per invocation but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765699/how-many-records-can-be-in-s3-put-event-lambda-trigger) discusses it.

Comment: I am trying to copy the objects to another bucket pre-delete for archival purposes.  These are the specs I was given which seemed odd to me as well...  Perhaps they meant batch copy?  In which case my question still stands:  How can I make a test event of multiple items?  (Typing this before reading your blog post, which I will do next)

Comment: How to make a test event for multiple objects? I would make sure the Lambda function prints the event in a useful format (JSON) and then trigger the Lambda function by deleting a test object from the S3 bucket. Fetch the log from CloudWatch Logs, copy the event from it, modify to include multiple test objects, then save as your test event. You won't be able to trigger your Lambda function pre-delete. You'll have to solve this differently, and be aware of S3 Lifecycle, which can transition objects to different storage tiers for archiving (or can delete them after N days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The s3 event you need to subscribe to is s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete that by [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html) is used to track an object **or a batch** of objects being removed:

> By using the ObjectRemoved event types, you can enable notification when an object or a batch of objects is removed from a bucket.

You can expect an event structured as detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html).

However since in the comment you said you just wanted to "copy the objects pre-delete to another bucket" you may want to explore [S3 buckets versioning capabilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html).
Enabling versioning will allow you to preserve in a "deleted" state the objects, leaving room for future restores, as per delete workflow [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/versioning-workflows.html).